# jQuery JSON array find if date is between

Tags: arrays, json, datepicker

So, I have a JSON array that has "Start Date", "End Date" & "Price". I also have a while loop that looks for the dates between my two selected dates with a datepicker. I want to compare my selected/between dates with the JSON array to get the price within that date range for each day.

My JSON array

```
var json = [
{
   "start_date": "12-18-2015",
   "end_date": "01-03-2016",
   "price": "99"
},
{
   "start_date": "01-04-2016",
   "end_date": "02-17-2016",
   "price": "75"
},
{
   "start_date": "02-18-2016",
   "end_date": "02-21-2016",
   "price": "69"
},
{
   "start_date": "02-22-2016",
   "end_date": "03-17-2016",
   "price": "75"
},
{
   "start_date": "03-18-2016",
   "end_date": "03-27-2016",
   "price": "99"
},
{
   "start_date": "03-28-2016",
   "end_date": "05-26-2016",
   "price": "75"
},
{
   "start_date": "05-27-2016",
   "end_date": "09-05-2016",
   "price": "99"
},
{
   "start_date": "09-06-2016",
   "end_date": "11-17-2016",
   "price": "75"
},
{
   "start_date": "11-18-2016",
   "end_date": "11-28-2016",
   "price": "99"
},
{
   "start_date": "12-19-2016",
   "end_date": "01-01-2017",
   "price": "99"
}
];

for (var key in json) {
    var start_date = json[key].start_date;
    var end_date = json[key].end_date;
    var price = json[key].price;
}
```

Checking between dates from input fields:

```
var startD = jQuery("#arrival").datepicker("getDate");
var endD = jQuery("#depart").datepicker("getDate");
var StartDate = new Date(startD);

var between = [];

while (StartDate<= endD) {
    between.push(new Date(StartDate));
    StartDate.setDate(StartDate.getDate() + 1);
}

console.log(between);
```

Here is a running snippet:

```js
var json = [{
  "start_date": "12-18-2015",
  "end_date": "01-03-2016",
  "price": "99"
}, {
  "start_date": "01-04-2016",
  "end_date": "02-17-2016",
  "price": "75"
}, {
  "start_date": "02-18-2016",
  "end_date": "02-21-2016",
  "price": "69"
}, {
  "start_date": "02-22-2016",
  "end_date": "03-17-2016",
  "price": "75"
}, {
  "start_date": "03-18-2016",
  "end_date": "03-27-2016",
  "price": "99"
}, {
  "start_date": "03-28-2016",
  "end_date": "05-26-2016",
  "price": "75"
}, {
  "start_date": "05-27-2016",
  "end_date": "09-05-2016",
  "price": "99"
}, {
  "start_date": "09-06-2016",
  "end_date": "11-17-2016",
  "price": "75"
}, {
  "start_date": "11-18-2016",
  "end_date": "11-28-2016",
  "price": "99"
}, {
  "start_date": "12-19-2016",
  "end_date": "01-01-2017",
  "price": "99"
}];

var allTogether = "";
for (var key in json) {
  var start_date = json[key].start_date;
  var end_date = json[key].end_date;
  var price = json[key].price;

  allTogether += start_date + " - " + end_date + " $" + price + "<br />";
}
$('#json').html(allTogether);


var dates3 = $("#arrival2_2, #depart2_2").datepicker({
  minDate: 2,
  showOn: "both",

  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.class == "arrival2_2" ? "minDate" : "30",
      instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
        selectedDate, instance.settings);
    dates3.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    if ($("#depart2_2").val() != '') {
      var arrivalDate = $("#arrival2_2").datepicker("getDate");
      var departureDate = $("#depart2_2").datepicker("getDate");
      var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    }
  },
  onClose: function(selectedDate) {

    var ar1 = $("#arrival2_2").datepicker("getDate");
    var dep1 = $("#depart2_2").datepicker("getDate");

    $("#arrival2").val(ar1);
    $("#depart2").val(dep1);
    checkavailability();
  }
});

var startD = jQuery("#arrival2_2").datepicker("getDate");
var endD = jQuery("#depart2_2").datepicker("getDate");
var currentDate = new Date(startD);

var between = [];

while (currentDate <= endD) {
  between.push(new Date(currentDate));
  currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
}

$('#results').html(between.join('<br> '));
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
    $(function() {
      //$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  Arrival:
  <input type="text" id="arrival2_2" name="obj[Arrival]" class="input unitsearch" value="01/20/2016"> Departure:
  <input type="text" id="depart2_2" name="obj[Departure]" class="input unitsearch" value="01/25/2016">


  <p>Dates from Arrival to Departure:</p>
  <div id="results"></div>

  <p>JSON output date range and price:</p>
  <div id="json"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a simple loop over the array like:

```
var getPrices = function(begin, end, input)
{
  var prices = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
    var startDate = new Date(input[i].start_date);
    var endDate = new Date(input[i].end_date);
    if (startDate <= end && endDate >= begin) // input[i] overlaps with [begin, end]
    {
      // arrange the boundaries
      if (startDate < begin)
      {
        startDate = begin;
      }
      if (endDate > end)
      {
        endDate = end;
      }
      prices.push({ StartDate: startDate, EndDate: endDate, Price: input[i].price });
    }
  }
  return prices;
};

var prices = getPrices(new Date("01-01-2016"), new Date("12-01-2016"), json);
```

If you need the price for each separate day, then the resulting array should be expanded:

```
var expandDays = function(prices)
{
  var dailyPrices = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < prices.length; i++)
  {
    var current = new Date(prices[i].StartDate);
    var end = prices[i].EndDate;
    while (current <= end)
    {
      dailyPrices.push({ Date: new Date(current), Price: prices[i].Price });
      current.setDate(current.getDate() + 1);
    }
  }
  return dailyPrices;
};

dailyPrices = expandDays(prices);
```

Comment: That looks like it would work! Where would you implement that though? See JSFiddle example here. https://jsfiddle.net/tu4nadog/2/

Comment: @TylerRobinson well you need to call the methods whenever the dates change, so for instance you can call it in your onClose event handler.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It took a lot of editing of the example you gave, but I got it to work!